# Is there a function in C# that returns grammar suggestions from MS Word document?

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I am working on project in ***.Net*** on ***Windows*** in ***C#*** language.

I would like to get grammar suggestions from ***MS Word***.
Now I am using ***Microsoft.Office.Interop*** and found a function that returns spelling suggestions (`expression. GetSpellingSuggestions`).
I also found function that show me corrections but opens a dialog from MS Office and I need choose one suggestion.

Is there a function that returns grammar suggestion or is it possible to get it from dialog that is opened from MS (via `_Document.CheckGrammar` Method)?

Comment: please add more informations about which platform you are using , it could be helpful to answer to your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Word object model doesn't provide anything for that. The best what you can do is to highlight grammar mistakes in Word by using the [Document.CheckGrammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.checkgrammar?view=vsto-2017) method.

Comment: So I am sure now that is not possible. Thanks.